# How can I redirect a URL for post request using AWS lambda?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, redirect, aws-lambda, gateway

These results are for GET and POST requests response through API gateway and lambda. used same lambda function, but when i used post method of API gateway, response just shows me JSON. what should i have to do?

[when i used post req](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzqhX.png)

[when i used get req](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8quXm.png)
it's my lambda function

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   const response = {
    statusCode: 301,
    headers: {
      Location: 'https://google.com',
    }
  };

  return callback(null, response);
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the new `async/await` pattern when defining my aws lambdas :

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
 // do stuff...
}
```

you usually don't need the `context`, unless you want to use some aws-related info regarding your lambda. 
I have a helper function that is re-used a lot inside the code base

```
function proxyResponse(inBody, inStatusCode = null, headers = {}, event = null) {
  if (!isApiGateway(event)) {
    if (inBody instanceof Error) {
      throw inBody;
    }
    return inBody;
  }
  let statusCode = inStatusCode;

  let body;
  if (inBody instanceof Error) {
    statusCode = statusCode || INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    body = JSON.stringify({
      message: inBody.message,
      code: statusCode,
    });
  } else if (inBody instanceof Object) {
    body = JSON.stringify(inBody);
  } else {
    body = inBody;
  }

  const [origin] = event ? caseHandler(event.headers, 'origin') : [];

  return {
    statusCode: statusCode || 200,
    body,
    headers: Object.assign({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,x-api-key,Authorization',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': origin,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT',
    }, headers),
  };
}
```

and another one :

```
function caseHandler(mixedCaseObject, inputKey) {
  if (!mixedCaseObject || !inputKey) {
    return [];
  }
  return Object.keys(mixedCaseObject)
    .filter((key => key.toLowerCase() === inputKey.toLowerCase()))
    .map(key => mixedCaseObject[key]);
}
```

and this one :

```
function isApiGateway(event) {
  return (!!event.httpMethod && !!event.headers && !!event.requestContext);
}
```

so inside the lambda whenever I want to return something I use this helper functions :

```
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try{
 // do stuff...
 return proxyResponse(YOUR_CUSTOM_BODY_OBJECT, Api.HTTP.OK, {}, event);
 } catch(error) {
 return proxyResponse(error, Api.HTTP.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, {}, event);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The GET request will return any content provided in the response. In this case, it is the JSON object *response*. For POST requests the same *response* object is being returned back to the API Gateway which is then returning it back as-is to the client.

Perhaps the documentation here could be of help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html